# Derivation of hall coefficient for semiconductors

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductor-physics

I was wondering how hall effect works in semiconductors. While looking up in the internet, I came across the following formula for the hall coefficient $R_H=\frac{E}{jB}$ in Wikipedia ($E$ is electric field, $j$ is current density and $B$ is magnetic field)...

$${\displaystyle R_{\mathrm {H} }={\frac {p\mu _{\mathrm {h} }^{2}-n\mu _{\mathrm {e} }^{2}}{e(p\mu _{\mathrm {h} }+n\mu _{\mathrm {e} })^{2}}}}$$

Where $p$ and $n$ are hole and electron density,$\mu_h$ and $\mu_e$ are hole and electron mobility, and e is the elementary charge. I tried to prove it and searched in the internet for the proof, but couldn't find any. Can anybody please tell me how to prove it or where I can find a proof?

Comment: Have a read of https://www.webcitation.org/5c0UeBBsZ which was an article link in the Wikipedia article on the Hall effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect#cite_note-Kasap2001-8

Comment: [here you can find your answer !](http://www.physics.pub.ro/Referate/FILS_Engleza/BN120_ENGLEZA/III_7_Hall%20Effect.pdf)